# How to display something like "it's empty here" when there is nothing to show in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my fragment activity:

```
public class cgpa_frag extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerview;
    adapter_cgpa ac;

    ArrayList<POJO> cgpaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    public cgpa_frag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cgpa_frag, container, false);
        recyclerview=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rc2);
        cgpaArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        ac= new adapter_cgpa(cgpaArrayList);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL,true));
        recyclerview.setAdapter(ac);


        Fetchdata2();
        return view;
    }
    private void Fetchdata2()
    {
        dbmanager db= new dbmanager(getContext());

        Cursor cursor= db.fetch_data2();

        if (cursor!= null) {

            // cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                POJO pj = new POJO();
                pj.setCname(cursor.getString(0));
                pj.setNo_of_sems(cursor.getString(1));
                pj.setCgpa(cursor.getString(2));
                pj.setPercentage(cursor.getString(3));
                pj.setSchemec(cursor.getString(4));
                cgpaArrayList.add(pj);
            }

            ac = new adapter_cgpa(cgpaArrayList);


        }

    }
```

This is fragment_cgpa_frag.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".drawernav.bottom_navi.recycler_view.cgpa_frag">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rc2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

How to display something like "it's empty here"  when there is nothing to show in recycler view? I have tried doing it in several ways but I did not get the output. Please tell me how can I do it. Any help would be acknowledged and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have one TextView in your xml. Give it a good name lets say tv_noContent.

Put one condition in your code before you update your adapter.

```
if(cgpaArrayList.isEmpty()){
   recyclerview.setVisibility(View.Gone);
   tv_noContent.setVisibility(View.Visible)
   tv_noContent.setText("Its empty here");

}else{
  tv_noContent.setVisibility(View.Gone);
  recyclerview.setVisibility(View.Visible);
  //Update your adapter here
}
```

Also I would recommend you to use camel case while naming your class.
Certainly cgpa_frag this name for Fragment class produces code smell. Rather name it CgpaFragment. Which is more readable and makes sense as well. 
Also don't create another instance of your adapter. Instead have a method in your adapter.

```
public void updateRecyclerList(ArrayList cgpaArrayList){
    this.cgpaArrayList.clear();
    this.cgpaArrayList.addAll(cgpaArrayList);
    notifyDatasetChange();
}
```

Your recycler view adapter will take care of your updated list. You are creating extra overhead with new adapter object. It will be created every time you want to show new data. Having a method in your adapter will only refresh your list. And will not create new UI.
Hope this will help you. Happy coding

Comment: I am not properly getting what you have to say. Can you please make the changes in my code and show me. I will verify your answer after that.